# The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request. When try to login with facebook in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, facebook-oauth

I am try to login with a user with Facebook account in my website, but the applcation gives me error that The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

Below is my code:

```
public string WebRequest(Method method, string url, string postData)
{

    HttpWebRequest webRequest = null;
    StreamWriter requestWriter = null;
    string responseData = "";    

    webRequest = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
    webRequest.Method = method.ToString();
    webRequest.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;
    webRequest.UserAgent = "[You user agent]";
    webRequest.Timeout = 50000;


    if (method == Method.POST)
    {
        webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        //POST the data.
        requestWriter = new StreamWriter(webRequest.GetRequestStream());

        try
        {
            requestWriter.Write(postData);
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }

        finally
        {
            requestWriter.Close();
            requestWriter = null;
        }
    }

    responseData = WebResponseGet(webRequest);
    webRequest = null;
    return responseData;
}
```

****It gives me error in this method:****

```
 public string WebResponseGet(HttpWebRequest webRequest)
{
    StreamReader responseReader = null;
    string responseData = "";

    try
    {
        responseReader = new      StreamReader(webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
        responseData = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
    }
    catch
    {
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream().Close();
        responseReader.Close();
        responseReader = null;
    }

    return responseData;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ooo been a while since Iv'e played with webRequest but I think your problem might be

```
webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream().Close();
```

in the finally block. Since you've already called

```
webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()
```

in the body of try block. Documentation states:

> The GetResponse method sends a request to an Internet resource and
>   returns a WebResponse instance. If the request has already been
>   initiated by a call to GetRequestStream, the GetResponse method
>   completes the request and returns any response.

Therefore as I read it, the response had already been returned in the try block and then when you call it again in the finally block, it fails...since it's already been retrieved. Just comment out that line and see how you go. The StreamReader should close the underlying connection when you close it.

So try:

```
public string WebResponseGet(HttpWebRequest webRequest)
{
    StreamReader responseReader = null;
    string responseData = "";

    try
    {
        responseReader = new StreamReader(webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
        responseData = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
    }
    catch
    {
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        responseReader.Close();
    }

    return responseData;
}
```